# jQuery String Contains Manipulation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

In most languages like C# for example given a string you can test (boolean) if that string contains another string, basically a subset of that string.

```
string x = test2;


if(x.contains("test"))
    // do something
```

How can I do this in a simple way with Javascript/Jquery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Method like String.contains() in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/method-like-string-contains-in-javascript)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

This is done with [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/indexOf), however it returns -1 instead of False if not found.

*Syntax* 
`string.indexOf(searchValue[, fromIndex])`

*Parameters* 
`searchValue` - 
A string representing the value to search for. 
`fromIndex` - 
The location within `string` to start the search from. It can be any integer between 0 and the length of `string`. The default value is 0.

*Return* 
The first index in `string` at which the start of the substring can be found, or -1 if `string` does not contain any instances of the substring.

Comment: I see `indexOf` is case-sensitive. To do case-insesitive compare i use `if(t.toUpperCase().indexOf(s.toUpperCase()) >= 0) { /* found */ }`

Answer (score 22):

As Paolo and cletus said, you can do it using indexOf().

Valid to mention is that it is a javascript function, not a jQuery one.

If you want a jQuery function to do this you can use it:

```
jQuery.fn.contains = function(txt) { return jQuery(this).indexOf(txt) >= 0; }
```

Comment: You have a bug in this implementation: if the searched string starts with txt, it will return false.  Use >= instead of >.

Comment: Corrected for the comment by Jacob

Comment: `jQuery(this)` returns a jQuery object, not a string. `indexOf` doesn't exist within that jQuery object. `this` will also not be a string, so you'll need to know which part of `this` you want to check for `txt`. Maybe `return this.src.indexOf(txt) >= 0;`?

Answer (score 13):

The indexOf operator works for simple strings. If you need something more complicated, it's worth pointing out that [Javascript supports regular expressions](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/JavaScript/Regular-expressions-in-JavaScript/6/).

Answer (score 4):

A simple contains can also be useful for example:

```
<div class="test">Handyman</div>


$(".test:contains('Handyman')").html("A Bussy man");
```

Answer (score 3):

A working example, using just indexOf and jQuery

```
// Add span tag, if not set
$(document).ready(function(c) {
  $('div#content ul.tabs li a').each(function(c){
    // Add span wrapper if not there already
    if( $(this).html().indexOf('span') == -1){
      $(this).html('<span class="tab">' + $(this).html() + '</span>');
    }
  });
});
```

DT

Comment: Are you Dave Thomas of Wendy's? If so, I ate there for lunch. Great burger.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement this

```
function function1() {
    var m = document.all.myDiv.contains(myB);
    if (m == true){ 
        m = "YES"
    } else {
        m = "NO"
    }
    alert(m)
}
```