# How to check if current URL ends in a specific pattern

Tags: javascript, url

How do I check if the current URL ends in: `#!/about` or `#!/ask` using JavaScript?

Comment: You need JavaScript, not jQuery.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Already edited. Maybe the [tag:jQuery] tag should be kept since plugins might be recommended.

Comment: you could use indexof
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800265/jquery-string-contains-manipulation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.location.hash` contains the current hash code, so basically:

```
if(window.location.hash === '#!/about') {
    // Do something
} else if(window.location.hash === '#!/ask') {
    // Do something else
}
```

You can use it however you need to.

Edit: As zzzzBov points out, if you need some jQuery, put it in a `$(document).ready` handler. ;)

Comment: but you didn't use any jQuery! :-p

Comment: @zzzzBov Sometimes you never need to :-)

Answer (score 2):

To fetch the current url using jQuery

```
$(location).attr('href');
```

Here's the code snippet

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var url=$(location).attr('href');
var match1 = arr.match('#!/about');
var match2 = arr.match('#!/ask');
if(match1){
   alert("match1 found");
          } else if{
   alert("match2 found");
          }
});
```